# Vaadin14 login-form css selector for shadow-root

Tags: css, web-component, shadow-dom, vaadin-flow

I have a vaadin-login-form that has the default css styles applied to it. The DOM looks like this [image]

My question is how can I use a css selector for styling the label part of the vaadin-button-container ?
I'm using a css file that's being used on my LoginView like so:

```
@CssImport(value = "./styles/login.css", themeFor = "vaadin-login-form")
```

I was able to style the `vaadin-login-submit` part with

```
[part="vaadin-login-submit"] {
    background-color: #0061ff;
}
```

in my css file but since the label part is inside the shadow dom I do not know how to select it for applying the proper css.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is not the correct `::part` syntax you are using.

- See spec: https://drafts.csswg.org/css-shadow-parts/#part
- and https://meowni.ca/posts/part-theme-explainer/

`[part=...]` is just a regular CSS attribute selector, that can indeed NOT pierce shadowDOM

`::part(label)` should do the job

Proof nested shadowRoots can be styled with ::part:

```html
<style>
  ::part(shadowdiv) {
    color: red;
    font-weight: bold;
  }
</style>

<custom-element></custom-element>

<script>
  window.CEdepth = 0;
  customElements.define("custom-element", class extends HTMLElement {
    constructor() {
      super().attachShadow({mode: 'open'})
      if (window.CEdepth++ < 5) {
        this.shadowRoot.innerHTML = `
<div part='shadowdiv'>Hello Web Component #${window.CEdepth}
<custom-element></custom-element><div/>`;
      }
    }
  })
</script>
```

Comment: ::part(label) indeed does work but it selects all the elements having a part named label, while my end-goal was to select only the label that is nested under an element of type <vaadin-button part="vaadin-login-submit">

Comment: Then make your selector more specific, or place the selector not in global CSS but deeper down in a shadowRoot